# How to import an object from another file using a variable name in typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm not sure how to articulate what I'm trying to do so it's hard to find specific answers, but here goes.

If I have simple files with individual objects like

`typeOne.ts`

```
export const types = {
    name: 'blah'
    ...
}
```

`typeTwo.ts`

```
export const types = {
    name: 'blehh'
    ...
}
```

I have another class somewhere that will take the name of which one to pull in and perform functions

```
public getTypes(typeName: string) {
    return {typeName from typeOne ... typeTwo ...} // how to import here?
}
```

And so I can call it basically

```
const theTypes = this.getTypes('typeOne');
```

or

```
const theTypes = this.getTypes('typeTwo');
```

So that is what I'm trying to achieve so that the `getTypes` function is generic and does not need to define each one individually ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alias your imports

```js
import { types as typeOne } from "./typeOne"
import { types as typeTwo } from "./typeTwo"
import { Type } from "./Type"

const allTypes = { typeOne, typeTwo }

const getTypes = (typeName: keyof typeof allTypes): Type =>
  allTypes[typeName]
```

```js
// Type.ts
export interface Type {
  name: string
}
```

---

An other approach to the `getTypes` function might look like...

```js
const getTypes = (typeName: string): Type => {
  switch (typeName) {
    case "typeOne" :
      return typeOne
    case "typeTwo" :
      return typeTwo
    default :
      throw new Error(`Unknown type "${typeName}"`)
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! do we need to do the allTypes combination and typeof check ?

Comment: @yoyoma I guess not, I was just trying to make it easy and type-safe to access the appropriate object. You could use a `switch(typeName)` or something like that

Comment: i appreciate the options, yeh I didn't think about simple switch case, thank you